# iOS AVAUDIO: EXC_ BAD_ACCESS in AudioUnitRender when coming from Background

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I've went through all the resources I could find before posting a question myself, but I just could not get any answers to my problem, so here goes:

In my iOS app, I am recording audio using the microphone, then fetching this audio using AdioUnitRender() and sending it to the delegate.

This all works well until the app comes from the background, where I get a an error at AudioUnitRender:

AURemoteIO::IOThread (15): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x102044000)

Enabling zombie objects to see more information did not work for me.

My code:

```
func inputCallback(
    inRefCon:UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
    ioActionFlags:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBusNumber:UInt32,
    inNumberFrames:UInt32,
    ioData:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus {
    
    let sm = Unmanaged<AudioManager>.fromOpaque(inRefCon).takeUnretainedValue()
    if (!sm.playing) {
        return noErr
    }
    if (sm.delegates.count < 1) {
        return noErr
    }
    guard let inUnit = sm.inputUnit else { return noErr }
    
    let listPtr = sm.audioBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer
        
    let status = AudioUnitRender(inUnit,
                                 ioActionFlags,
                                 inTimeStamp,
                                 inBusNumber,
                                 inNumberFrames,
                                 listPtr)

    if (status != noErr) {
        return status;
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for delegate in sm.delegates {
            delegate.processSampleData(inputDataList: listPtr, frameCount: Int(inNumberFrames), numInputChannels:  sm.inputChannels)
        }
    }
    return noErr
}
```

Error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItPo3.png

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, however it does not happen consistently. Sometimes, when coming back from background, I have exactly the same exception upon AudioUnitRender call. Any progress on this @DaVincr ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. In the end, i got rid of the issue, but can't quite remember how I did it. Ill will see if i can look it up.

Comment: @MarcelloCarrozzino it appears as i have changed the AVAudioSession category to .playAndRecord with no options set. Looking at my commits, i have implemented a listener to audio interruption, this helped me greatly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions

I hope you can resolve your issues.

Comment: Thank you indeed for your help, I will look through that hoping to find a solution